# Getting a syntax error for trying to get values from two different databases

Tags: sql, join

```
select * 
from DB1.schemaA.table1 as t1
outer join DB2.schemaA.table1 as t2
on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

error being - *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'join'*

Comment: Syntax error. Should be `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, `RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN` or `FULL [OUTER] JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer join query syntax is not correct, please use `full outer join`

Since you didn't mention which SQL database being used, so here is a general guide: [W3School SQL FULL OUTER JOIN Keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp)

Comment: Hi @jarlh, didn't come here to debate about W3School content quality, since the author did not provide the type of db he's using, so I cannot recommend the precise document for that. The guideline provided is minimal, easy to get the idea of how this work for new user. If you find that link faulty, have error, or have any better source, please feel free to let us know in the comment, instead of using harsh word like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing:

`select *  from DB1.schemaA.table1 as t1 full outer join DB2.schemaA.table1 as t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID;`